# infinite direct product of integers is not an essential submodule of infinite direct product of rationals.

Tags: modules, abelian-groups

Just as the title says im trying to prove that the infinite direct product of integers with itself is not an essential Z-submodule of the infinite direct product of the rational numbers with itself. Essential meaning that its intersection with any other nonzero submodule is nonzero. What this basically comes down to is finding a submodule that does not contain any nonzero integer sequences. Im asking for any advice towards this direction.

Comment: When you say "infinite direct product of ... with itself", I think you mean "infinite direct product of copies of ...". I.e., you are looking at $\Bbb{Z}^I$ and $\Bbb{Q}^I$ where $I$ is some infinite index set. If so, see if you can think of an element $q \in \Bbb{Q}^I$ such that $nq \not\in \Bbb{Z}^I$ for any $n \in \Bbb{Z}$. Now consider the  submodule generated by $q$.

Comment: It's tempting to think that the direct product of injective hulls would be the injective hull of the direct product, but apparently the hull is strictly smaller than $\prod \mathbb Q$!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: If a submodule $N$ with the property you are looking for exists, then there exists such a submodule $N$ which is cyclic (just take the submodule generated by any nonzero element of $N$).  So you may as well look for an example of $N$ that is cyclic.  That is, you want to find some element of the module such that no nonzero multiple of it has all integer coordinates.